# relation between AGT- conjecture and CNV-correspondence

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, quantum-field-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there any relation between AGT conjecture 0906.3219 and the 4d-2d correspondence of 1006.3435 ?

For pure SYM of  $\mathcal{N}=2$ , SU(2) guage group thoery, we know the explicit instanton partition function, 
can we read BPS spectrum from instanton partition function?
Is there wall-crossing effect for instanton partition function?

Comment: The subject matter sounds interesting, but to make it a useful MO question it would be very helpful to add some explanations and context about the conjecture and correspondence in question.

Comment: I agree with David's comment.

By the way, it seems that all these correspondances people are interested in are the shadow of a to-be-constructed-theory in 6d.


Comment: This has now found an answer on PhysicsOverflow: http://www.physicsoverflow.org/23602/relation-between-agt-conjecture-and-cnv-correspondence?show=23778#a23778